# Have any third parties used Maine or Arizona's public financing in their campaigns?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance, third-party

I cannot find evidence for a third party using the public financing option for either state.  I can see nothing preventing it and assume they have at some point.  Specifically I'm referring to the $5 multiple donations needed that then lead the state to fully fund their campaign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maine's [2018 Candidate list](https://www.maine.gov/ethics/pdf/2018CandidateContactList03062018.xlsx) (Excel) shows that of 211 candidates choosing to use the public financing option, 140 were Democrats, 54 Republicans, 16 Unenrolled, and 1 Green.

There are additional reports available on [Maine's Governmental Ethics and Elections Practices](https://www.maine.gov/ethics/disclosure/candidates.htm) site, but the 2018 list alone is sufficient to answer that third party candidates have used public financing in Maine.

Arizona's [Historical Candidate Data](https://www.azcleanelections.gov/en/arizona-elections/historical-candidate-data) page shows 18 third party candidates (Green, Libertarian, and Independent) availing themselves of the public financing option since it was enacted.